# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference

Tags: php, mysqli

This is the code.

```
$emailQuery = "SELECT * FROM `userprofile` WHERE `user_deped_email`=? OR `user_email`=? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($emailQuery);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $depedemail OR $personalemail);
$stmt->execute();
$query_run = $stmt->get_result();
$userCount = $query_run->num_rows;
```

I am not sure if I did the right thing. I need to pass an option to bind. The user has the option whether to enter either of his email accounts and only one account is needed.

Comment: `$depedemail OR $personalemail` is wrong.

Comment: I don't know what `$sql_u = "SELECT * FROM `userprofile` WHERE `user_name`='$username'";` is but you need to remove it or use prepared statements for it too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 placeholders in your query so you need to bind two variables.

```
//                       V        and      V
WHERE `user_deped_email`=? OR `user_email`=?
```

`bind_param()` should be:

```
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $depedemail, $personalemail);
```

`$depedemail OR $personalemail` is an expression, and an expression is not a variable. You can't pass the result of an expression by reference.